# Delete method gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: json, reactjs, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I have made a simple request from reactjs to the spring boot app then the following error has occurred.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Product is not null in the reactjs but I think the problem is during the calling part

**spring boot**

*CrosConfig class*

```
@Configuration
public class CrosConfig  {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer crosConfigurer() {

        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("DELETE");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

*Controller class*

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {


private ProductService productService;

@Autowired
private ProductController(ProductService productService) {
    this.productService = productService;
}

  @DeleteMapping(value = "/delete", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public void deleteProduct(@RequestBody Product product) throws Exception {
        
        if (product.getProductId() != 0 && !product.getProductName().trim().isEmpty() &&
                product.getNumberOfUnitInCartoon() != 0 && product.getPriceOfCartoon() != 0.0)
            productService.deleteProduct(product);
        else
            throw new NullPointerException();
    }

}
```

**reactjs**

```
deleteProduct=(product)=>{

        console.log(`${product.productId}`)
        console.log(`${product.productName}`)


        fetch('http://localhost:9090/products/delete',{
            method:'DELETE',
            headers:{
                'content-type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                 product:product
            })
        })
            .then(()=>{
                this.setState({
                     isLoaded:true
                })
            },error=>{
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded:true,
                    error
                })
            });
        this.getAllProducts();
    }
```

*stack trace*

```
2020-09-15 14:44:33.265 ERROR 2396 --- [nio-9090-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.benz.assignment.web.controller.ProductController.deleteProduct(ProductController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:an]............
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace in your console (I mean, the console where you are actually executing your spring boot app)?  Also, your code snippets do not show how the controller's `productService` field is defined.

A suggestion: do not throw a `NullPointerException` in your else statement but use a more specific exception type like `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: i will update stacktrace

Comment: As lines are not numbered in your snippet, could you point line 54 of your controller please?

Comment: line 54 --->    throw new NullPointerException();

Comment: Well, the NullPointerException is throw by your code i.e. the throw statement in your else case. That statement is not executed because `product` is null, it is because of the condition you wrote. So... what is your question exactly?

Comment: my product is not null but spring boot consumes it as null.

Comment: where is the wrong? I think the problem is in the API request calling part

Comment: @NafazBenzema Did you get actual object in backend? Because i thought product or some data of product which you used in condition could be null.

Comment: You do not need to create an extra level. Instead of `JSON.stringify({product:product})` try to use `JSON.stringify(product)`

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you provided shows that the `NullPointerException` is actually thrown by your own code (in your else statement). So the `product` argument of your controller's method is **not** null but your `if` condition evaluates to `false`. So there is nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michal Zoiber and others anyway the problem was in the request body. The following way gives the solution

```
fetch('http://localhost:9090/products/delete',{
            method:'DELETE',
            headers:{
                'content-type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(product)
        })
            .then(()=>{
                this.setState({
                     isLoaded:true
                },()=>{
                    this.getAllProducts();
                })
            },error=>{
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded:true,
                    error
                })
            });
    }
```